# Codeigniter - Model, checking that values are in row

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, if-statement

I need to check that two variables match fields in a row where the `id = x`.

Firstly I checked that the row with ID x exists I then need to check that both $category and $title are equal to the values in that row.

How can I compare the variables to the fields and return true if they match???

```
                function match_id($category,$id,$title)
{
    $this->db->where(array('id' => $id));
    $query = $this->db->get('news');
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0){

             foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            $data = array(
                'category' => $row->category,
                'title' => $row->title
            );
             }

             //If category == $category && title == $title, return true

        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($data['category'] == $category && $data['title']==$title)
{
return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just do the matching in query itself:

```
    $this->db->where(array('id' => $id,'title'=>$title,'category'=>$category));
    $query = $this->db->get('news');
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
            return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
```